# optimization on large volume of objects

Tags: java, performance, optimization

I have a process that gets a ResultSet from Oracle DB and then creates objects using returned data, then adds an object to the Map and eventually loads a map into in-memory data grid. My maximum resultSet may have 30 million records. I noticed that after processing about 14 million records an application slows down significantly. I have -Xmx=12G  and -Xms=512M. My application is deployed on WebLogic ver 12.2.0.1 and Java version 8_66.   I also noticed this message produced by managed server :

1. Possible too long JVM pause:

I am trying to figure how can I optimize either my code or JVM configuration. Here is the code

```
    MyObj myObj = null;

    while (rs.next()) {
        myObj = new Balance(rs.getString("Field1"), rs.getString("Field2"), rs.getString("Field3"),
                                   ....
        rs.getString("Field17"), rs.getString("Field18"), rs.getString("Field19"));

        Map<String, Account> myMap = new HashMap<>();
        myMap.put(rs.getString("FieldA"), new Account(rs.getString("FieldA"), rs.getDouble("FieldC"),
                rs.getString("FieldD"), Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.FALSE));
        myObj.setAccounts(myMap);

        myKey = myObj.getKey();

        existingObject = cacheMap.get(myKey);

        if (existingObject != null) {
            myObj = myObj.merge(existingObject);
        }

        cacheMap.put(myKey, myObj);
        recCount++;

        if (recCount % 250000 == 0) {
            logger.info("Processed " + recCount + " records.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need such a large map in memory? A better strategy would be to fetch only the stuff you need when you need it.

Comment: This is really a design problem. It seems like 12G is not enough for your program, so when garbage collector making an attempt to free unused object it stuck since most of the objects still in use.  In any case, if it too late to refactor - you can reorganize your loop. I think that you can change your `merge` strategy. I.e. check that object in cache map first,and then, if it is exist, add an additional entities into existing map, instead of constructing of ne map and merge it with existing.

Comment: I would recommend using a profiler to check what happens at runtime. By only seeing the code, my guess is that your possible pain points are: `rs#next`, `myMap#put`, `myObjsetAccounts`, `myObj#merge`, `cacheMap#put`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pagination and retrieve the dataset in chunks, then your program could start processing the current data chunck while the next data chunk is being retrieved etcetera. It will take less long to retrieve a resultset this way. Heres a good article about pagination in mySql https://www.xarg.org/2011/10/optimized-pagination-using-mysql/

Comment: I am using Statement.setFetchSize already and found a sweet spot. It's gotta be something else

Answer (score 0):

**Option:1**

If some of your fields value will be same `String`, then while creating `Balance` and `Account`, pls do `String.intern()`. This will give enourmous benefit with respect to memory foot print if there are redundant values.

In one of our applications with data of 2 lacs, we have seen benefit of 50% after `String.intern()`.

The code may look little ugly. But, with some utility methods, you can reduce the ugliness.

Code here

```
String str(ResultSet rs, String fieldName)
{
    String s = rs.getString(fieldName);
    return s == null ? null : s.intern();
}

void somemethod()
{
...
...

    while (rs.next()) {
        myObj = new Balance(str(rs, "Field1"), str(rs, "Field2"), str(rs, "Field3"), str(rs, "Field17"), str(rs, "Field18"), str(rs, "Field19"));

        Map<String, Account> myMap = new HashMap<>();
        myMap.put(str(rs, "FieldA"), new Account(str(rs, "FieldA"), str(rs, "FieldC"), str(rs, "FieldD"), Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.FALSE));
        myObj.setAccounts(myMap);

...
...
    }
...
}
```

**Option:2**

This is really a memory saver option...!

If you use Java 8 Update 20 or above, this behavior can be enabled for whole JVM by enabling the flag `XX:+UseStringDeduplication`. This will work if you use `G1` GC

Some ref [here](http://java-performance.info/java-string-deduplication/). You can search `XX:+UseStringDeduplication` for more references

**Option:3**

You can really think of what you do in that `merge()` operation to see for any functional change to bring down the memory requirement...

Comment: Option 4: Switching to Java 9 because of [compact strings](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254).